# After saving file using openpyxl i lost computing formulas

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have some formulas in my excel file and I need to put to this file data using python. I use openpyxl because i think this library is the most appropriate. The problem is when I wrote this file using openpyxl and I want to open this file again formulas which are inside doesn't compute and when I use Data Only mode I see "NaN" value, without this mode I see string with this formula.
How can I read value of this formula?

I tried to use other libraries but It still doesn't working.

```
dec1 = pd.read_excel(path).iloc[26, 10]

str_dat2 = datetime.now()
exe_app = xw.App(visible=False)
xlwb = xw.Book(path)
xlwb.sheets['HURT'].range("C17").value = 'BASE_Q-1-23'
xlwb.sheets['HURT'].range("E17").value = 0.25
xlwb.sheets['HURT'].range("F17").value = 1500
xlwb.save(path)
xlwb.close()
exe_app.quit()
stp_dat3 = datetime.now()-str_dat2
dec3 = pd.read_excel(path).iloc[26, 10]

str_dat1 = datetime.now()
wb = load_workbook(filename=path, read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
ws = wb['HURT']
ws['C17'] = 'BASE_Q-1-23'
ws['E17'] = 0.25
ws['F17'] = 1500
wb.save(path)
stp_dat2 = datetime.now()-str_dat1
dec2 = pd.read_excel(path).iloc[26, 10]
```

```
Before changing file (value): NIE
Before changing file (formula): =IF(J22=100%,IF(AND($F$15<>"",J27>0),"TAK","NIE"),"NIE")

After changing file (openpyxl): nan it lasted: 0:00:00.166674
After changing file (xlwings): TAK it lasted: 0:00:02.496538
```

Comment: Read the value of a formula? Openpyxl wont do that, it does not resolve formulas it creates/modifies xlsx files. If you want to resolve formulas then you need a lib that works with Excel like Xlwings. Explain more what you have tried using 'other libraries'

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. 
I added code above, because my description wasn't enough.
I checked xlwings and the result is what I need, but it takes definitely too long. 
File modification using openpyxl took 0:00:00.166674 vs xlwings 0:00:02.496538. 

When I saved file using xlwings I have file in the same mode like before, but when I saved file using openpyxl I got file in different mode (I have to click "enable content" to modify something) and for this reason pandas doesn't solve formulas. 
Is the way to change this?

Comment: I might expect that XLwings would be slower due to it having to open and interact with an Excel isntance. If speed is an issue maybe you can try making your changes with Openpyxl and then after saving open the wb again using Xlwings or win32com to refresh/update the formulas. This of course is not elegant and may not be desirable for time reasons so you have have to live with one or the other